# How to compute $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{4^{n-1}}{(\pi -1)^{2n}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I wrote as $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{4^{n-1}}{(\pi -1)^{2n}}=\frac{1}{4}\left(1+\left(\frac{4}{(\pi-1)^2}\right)^1+\left(\frac{4}{(\pi-1)^2}\right)^2+\cdots\right)=\frac14\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac {4}{(\pi-1)^2}}\right)$ is this approach correct? is there another way to compute? Thanks.

Comment: Your approach is perfectly correct.

Comment: It's important to note that $|\frac4{(\pi-1)^2}|<1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Another way :**

Rewrite
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4^{n-1}}{(\pi-1)^{2n}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^{2n-2}}{(\pi-1)^{2n}}=2^{-2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{2}{\pi-1}\right)^{2n},
$$
where the last form is $\dfrac14$ of an [infinite geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series) whose successive terms have a common ratio $r=\left(\dfrac{2}{\pi-1}\right)^{2}$.